# How to do a synchronous pause in asynchronous operation?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I want to implement a file copying process asynchronously in C# using `async`/`await`/`Task<T>`. The process should be non-blocking for the UI, so will be run in a separate Task. There are situations though, when the process needs to be paused and synchronous action must be performed.

For instance, it may happen, that a file, which is being copied, already exists in the target location. In this case, a modal dialog should appear, asking user what to do. The dialog should be modal in respect to the window, which shows progress of copying, and since showing it is a UI operation, it should be shown from the main thread. Moreover, if multiple copying tasks encounter the same situation, they should be handled one-by-one, not all at the same time.

What is the proper way of "synchronously pausing" a running task?

My only idea looks like following:

- Task keeps its whole state in a class instance
- When such situation happens, it terminates, returning a class containing:

  - Information on what happened
  - State instance
- This finishes the `await` call and caller can synchronously react to whatever happened in the `Task`.
- When user decides to continue process (e.g. replace the target file or rename copied one), the Task is re-executed with the state returned from the previous execution along with user's decision.

The pseudocode for this solution would look like following:

```cs
public async Task ExecuteProcess()
{
    UserDecision lastDecision = null;
    var state = new();

    bool finished = false;
    while (!finished)
    {
        var result = await DoExecuteProcess(state, lastDecision);
        if (result is UserChoiceResult)
        {
            lastDecision = AskUser();
        }
        else if (result is FinishedResult)
        {
            finished = true;
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported async task result");
    }
}
```

I'm wondering though, if there is a better solution for this problem, as this one seems a little bit sketchy for me (returning a "partially-done-requiring-more-information" result from async task).

Comment: Tasks are not running on a different thread necessarily. A single Thread can execute n-Tasks. Be aware that a single Task might also be executed / performed by a number of different Threads. If you want to pause and continue, you probably need to switch to Threading to have more control. You'd use a Task in situations in which you don't care when it finishes. You just start them and let them do their things. If you want to start, pause, cancel something whenever you want, use a Thread.

Comment: I really think you make it more complicated than need be. A copy can succeed or fail with a reason. So why not await the copy and handle possible failreasons on the calling context, which includes possible user interaction and loop...